# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : fatal SSL/TLS alert

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the following file, using `rvest` package:

```
page <- read_html("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55560/55560-0.txt")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
```

Comment: Works for me. I'm on W10, `rvest_0.3.2`.

Comment: Thanks, odd. Also on rvest_0.3.2 but on Windows 7. Don't think our different operating systems should make a difference though.

Comment: Have you tried turning R off and on again? /me hides

Comment: Haha, will try that in a short while.

Comment: I am getting the same message using GitHub desktop to clone a Git repository to my PC...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem when remoting to my work PC. Some websites work fine and others receive the error.

when I tried to access the websites using chrome I can't get onto the websites where I received the error, so I guess it could be something to do with banned sites/firewall issue.